# How to deal with hover binds for Bootstrap widgets within Backbone?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

Stupid question maybe.

If I use Backbone to bind methods to certain events, namely hover, how can I use Bootstrap's widgets that way?

Here's an example (coffee js mix, sorry):

```
events:
 'mouseover .whatever': 'showPopover'
```

I obviously don't want showPopover() to bind the popover, like this:

```
showPopover: ->
  $('.whatever').popover(options)
```

This will cause it to bind every time I hover .whatever, obviously.
Our current fix is to do something like this:

```
 showPopover: ->
   $('.whatever').popover(show).popover(options)
```

It feels like it's binding every time. If you hover over it a couple times, it will start to flicker (again, seemingly bound each time you hover).

So, am I SOL? Do I need to just drop the Backbone event binding, do my bind via the attach method or something instead?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks, everyone :).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're binding to mouseover? If you're doing it for "just in time" performance gains, then I would suggest testing for the existence of the data which Bootstrap popover saves on your elements `bs.popover`.

```
showPopover: ->
    var popover = $('.whatever').data('bs.popover');
    if(!popover) $('.whatever').popover(options);
```

But unless you're really trying to get fancy, I'd put that kind of preparation into either `initialize` or `render`.

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.find('[data-toggle=popover]')
      .popover({
          placement: 'bottom'
      });
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/OlODUSe/1/edit)